# Hyperledger Composer Deploying Business Network Error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Could someone help me to resolved this error

```
this is what I input:  composer network start --networkName land- 
registry --networkVersion 0.0.1 --networkAdmin admin -- 
networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file networkadmin.card


Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: Unable to initalize 
channel. Attempted to contact 1 Peers. Last error was Error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: 
access denied: channel [composerchannel] creator org [Org1MSP]
```

Comment: you MAY have an error in your `connection.json` file that you used to build the `PeerAdmin@hlfv1` card. The channel definition is not known to your Fabric env - did you build this Fabric env yourself? - or - is this a localhost-based Dev Fabric (looks like) provided by the Hyperledger Composer docs page?  If you cannot resolve, then might suggest to do a teardown (see sequence below)

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Remove your old fabric-tools / fabric-dev-servers (whatever you've called it) directory

2. mkdir ~/fabric-tools && cd ~/fabric-tools     #inside the directory

3. curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/composer-tools/master/packages/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-dev-servers.tar.gz 

4. cd fabric-tools ; tar -xvf fabric-dev-servers.tar.gz

5. ./stopFabric.sh ; ./teardownFabric.sh ; ./fabric-tools/startFabric.sh
6. ./createPeerAdminCard.sh
7. cd ~/landreg-network/   # wherever your BNA file is etc

finally:

8. composer network install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --archiveFile land-registry@0.0.1.bna

9. composer network start --networkName land-registry --networkVersion 0.0.1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file networkadmin.card
```